# Elements inside arrays seem to be strings rather than signed numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, matrix

When I have code like

```
b = Array[Subscript[be, #] &, {3, 1}]
b = b /. {Subscript[be, k_] :> Subscript[-be, k] /; k > 1}
```

I am noticing that *Mathematica* does not accept the new element as a signed number, i.e., negative be but rather as a string object. Is there a way to fix this?

For example, the following code generates an error then when I am solving for Subscript[be, 2] but not when I solve for `Subscript[-be, 2]` which tells me that *Mathematica* looks at this more like a string than a number.

```
(m = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {3, 3}]) // MatrixForm
m = m /. Subscript[a, i_, j_] :> Subscript[a, j, i] /; j < i
b = Array[Subscript[be, #] &, {3, 1}]
b = b /. {Subscript[be, 1] -> 1, 
   Subscript[be, k_] :> Subscript[(-1)*be, k] /; k > 1}
p = Transpose[b].m.b
Solve[p == 0, Subscript[be, 2], Complexes]
```

Comment: If you are going to be spending a lot of time with matrices in Mathematica, you should probably stop using the `Subscript` function. This is mostly a formatting function (like `MatrixForm`) and will cause no end of grief.

Comment: Thanks @bills I agree it is painful. I solved it and wrote an answer.

Comment: I think what bills is trying to say is that instead of using `Subscript[a, ##]` you should use `a[##]`. It doesn't look as nice, but subscripts are really annoying to use in Mathematica, and should ideally be avoided.

Comment: The most most part I agree with bill, but why are you using `Subscript[-be, k]` rather than `-Subscript[be, k]`?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wrote in my answer. I am using the output to study the structure of the problem so I need it to be as humanly legible as possible.

Answer (score 1):

A way to solve this is making the following change the fourth line into

```
b = b /. {Subscript[be, 1] -> 1, 
   Subscript[be, k_] :> (-1)*Subscript[be, k] /; k > 1}
```

where we have taken the negative one out the Subscript function. This came from the kind comment by @bills that Subscript is mostly a formatting function whose output can become the numerical object.